# shmget fails with ENOMEM even though enough pages available

Tags: c++, linux, memory-management, shared-memory, huge-pages

We're getting odd behaviour when trying to allocate an approximately 10MB block of memory from huge pages. System is SL6.4 64-bit, recent Intel CPU, 64GB RAM.

Initially we allocated 20 huge pages which should be enough.

```
$ cat /proc/meminfo | grep Huge
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
HugePages_Total:      20
HugePages_Free:       20
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
```

Other huge page settings:

```
/proc/sys/kernel/shmall = 4294967296
/proc/sys/kernel/shmmax = 68719476736
/proc/sys/kernel/shmmni = 4096
/proc/sys/kernel/shm_rmid_forced = 0
```

shmget fails with ENOMEM. The only explanation I can find for this is in the man page which states "No memory could be allocated for segment overhead." but I haven't been able to discover what "segment overhead" is.

On another server with the same number of pages configured shmget returns successfully.

On the problem server we increased the number of huge pages to 100. The allocation succeeds but also allocates 64 2MB huge pages:

```
$ ipcs -m

------ Shared Memory Segments --------
key        shmid      owner      perms      bytes      nattch     status
0x0091efab 10223638   rsprod     600        2097152    1
0x0092efab 10256407   rsprod     600        2097152    1
0x0093efab 10289176   rsprod     600        2097152    1
0x0094efab 10321945   rsprod     600        2097152    1
0x0095efab 10354714   rsprod     600        2097152    1
0x0096efab 10387483   rsprod     600        2097152    1
...
0x00cdefab 12189778   rsprod     600        2097152    1
0x00ceefab 12222547   rsprod     600        2097152    1
0x00cfefab 12255316   rsprod     600        2097152    1
0x00d0efab 12288085   rsprod     600        2097152    1
0x00000000 12320854   rsprod     600        10485760   1
```

The code calling shmget is below. This is only being called once in the application.
    uint64_t GetHugePageSize()
    {
        FILE *meminfo = fopen("/proc/meminfo", "r");
        if(meminfo == NULL) {
            return 0;
        }

```
    char line[256];
    while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), meminfo)) {
        uint64_t zHugePageSize = 0;
        if(sscanf(line, "Hugepagesize: %lu kB", &zHugePageSize) == 1) {
            fclose(meminfo);
            return zHugePageSize*1024;
        }
    }

    fclose(meminfo);
    return 0;
}

char* HugeTableNew(size_t aSize, int& aSharedMemID)
{
    static const uint64_t sHugePageSize = GetHugePageSize();

    uint64_t zSize = aSize;
    // round up to next page size, otherwise shmat fails with EINVAL (22)
    const uint64_t HUGE_PAGE_MASK = sHugePageSize-1;
    if(aSize & HUGE_PAGE_MASK) {
        zSize = (aSize&~HUGE_PAGE_MASK) + sHugePageSize;
    }

    aSharedMemID = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, zSize, IPC_CREAT|SHM_HUGETLB|SHM_R|SHM_W);
    if(aSharedMemID < 0) {
        perror("shmget");
        return nullptr;
    }
...
```

Does anyone know:

- What causes the allocation to fail when there are enough free huge pages available?
- What causes the extra 2MB pages to be allocated?
- What "segment overhead" is?